# Why is HTML content not visible in some versions of Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Suppose I have a div whose content is dependent on the button click on top of that. The content of three button clicks are stores in variables `one`, `two` and `three`.

```
<div id="onebutton"></div>
<div id="twobutton"></div>
<div id="threebutton"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Using jQuery, when the `onebutton` div is clicked, I put the HTML content of variable `one` into the `content` div:

```
$('#content').html(one);
```

Now, what sometimes happens is that the content is present in the div, but it does not show. It sometimes shows when I hover the mouse over the div and gets shown in parts (i.e. the browser shows only some part of the div where my mouse is).

There is a tool called *Active X-Ray Googles*. When I activate it and take my mouse over the `content` div, it is also shown.

I do not know what is wrong. I have tested it in 20 versions of Chrome, but it does not work on one of them. The version it does not work on is the latest version of *Mac OS X Mavericks* on a *MacBook Pro Retina*.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: works on Chrome 38 on mavericks

Comment: i can probably give a link to the website https://smartican.com/popular/.  Then scroll down and click on the NGO  button. Then press on city, enter "delhi" chose "New Delhi" from below and press enter

Comment: did you try cloning the content of the divs instead? like `$('#content').html($('#onebutton').clone())`

Comment: Or reference the HTML directly: `$('#content').html($('#onebutton').html());`

Comment: You really need to put this in a jsFiddle. My bet is that there's something else on the site that's knocking this out. Probably nothing to do with Chrome.